# Closed Functions in Python

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm trying to write a function `bin_to_dec(s)` that takes a string of a binary number and converts it into the corresponding decimal number/integer.

I know there are probably built in ways to convert this but I am trying to accomplish it through recursion. This is what I have programmed so far

I keep getting a memory error. How can I edit my last statement to make this work?

Comment: I think he confused some variable names here....

Comment: recursion typically means you call the function from somewhere inside itself

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need to multiply the result of `s[0]` by 2 here at all; the least significant bit is either 0 or 1, not 0 or 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid recursion, it is not neccessary for what you are trying to do. I'd go with something like

```
def binToDec(s):
    total = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(s[::-1]):
        total += int(value) * 2**index
    return total

>>> binToDec('1100')
12
```

Same idea using a list comp:

```
def binToDec(s):
    return sum(int(value) * 2**index for index,value in enumerate(s[::-1]))
```

If you **really** want to do it recursively

```
def binToDec(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return int(s)
    else:
        return binToDec(s[-1]) + 2*binToDec(s[:-1])
```

Comment: You can save an expensive ``**`` by checking if it's just going to be zero anyway.

Comment: Hey, I use python and never had seen this syntax `s[::-1]`, would you mind point some source? Thanks.

Comment: It's called a [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html). Syntax is ``[start:stop:step]`` where an empty value is assumed to be ``[0:len(list):1]``. Note that *stop* is exclusive, so ``[0:2]`` gets you the first two elements, not the first three.

Comment: @DonaldWang Also keep in mind that Python lacks Tail Call Optimization, and has a stack-depth limit of ~1000 in the standard CPython implementation, so you're limited to less than 1000 bits for the recursive form. Not that that should be a problem here, but something to keep in mind when doing recursion in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def bin_to_dec(s):
if s == '0':
   return 0
elif s == '1':
    return 1
elif s[0] == '0':
    return bin_to_dec(s[1:])
else:
    return int(math.pow(2, len(s) - 1)) + (bin_to_dec(s[1:]))
```

Comment: I'm not sure. This works, but requires the math library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter (in lines) recursive version based on the one by @PeterPeiGuo:

```
def bin_to_dec(s):
    return int(s[-1]) + (len(s)>1 and 2*(bin_to_dec(s[:-1])))
```